# Select cases error

Tags: r

I am trying to select cases in R by doing the below however an error  is being shown:

```
Cluster1 <- bank[Cluster == "cluster1"]
Error in `[.data.frame`(bank, Cluster == "cluster1") : 
  object 'Cluster' not found
```

Comment: If `Cluster` is a column of your df you will need `bank$Cluster`. Also, data frames have both rows and columns, you are using just one index.

Comment: yes cluster is a column in my df. but if I will do Cluster1 <- bank(bank$Cluster == 'cluster1') another error is showing:Error in bank(bank$Cluster == "cluster1") : 
  could not find function "bank"

Comment: Square `[`!!! Like in the question...

Comment: still giving me the error:

c1<-newbank[newbank$Cluster=='cluster1']
Error in `[.data.frame`(newbank, newbank$Cluster == "cluster1") : 
  undefined columns selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Rui Barradas said in the comments, you need to add `bank$Cluster` if you filter using `[`. Which would look like this:

```
cluster1 <- bank[bank$Cluster == "cluster1",]
```

However, you can also do this easily with `dplyr`'s `filter` function:

```
cluster1 <- dplyr::filter(bank, Cluster == "cluster1")
```

Comment: But still when I am trying to use the first solution an error is showing:

Error in `[.data.frame`(bank, bank$Cluster == "cluster1") : 
  undefined columns selected

Comment: ok great worked :) thanks a lot